# delete specific lines with regex

Tags: text-processing

I would like a regex string to remove the second line, for example:

```
Word 1

Word 2
```

I have a blank line between words 1 and 2, I would like a regex string where I can specify which line I want to delete (something that works regardless of whether the line is blank).

I am using a third party site to run this command, and it only has regex support, at this point I am extremely limited

Thank you

Comment: do you want to remove 2nd non-empty line, in this case `Word 2`? or you just want to remove 2nd line of a file?

Comment: I would like to remove line number 2 (regardless of whether it is blank or not), I am using a third party platform and it has regex support only

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) There's probably a better approach than a regexp and even if a regex were the right approach, every tool supports different flavors (BRE, ERE, PCRE) with different extensions (word boundaries, backreferences, etc, and different default delimiters (e.g. `/`), etc. We'd need a lot more information about what you're trying to do and with which tools to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Delete a line

```
sed 'Xd' inputfile
```

Where `X` is the line number. In your case is 2.

Comment: I don't think regex could satisfy what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately sed will not work because I am using a third party site to execute this string, it only has regex support, at this point I am extremely limited, would you know how to solve my problem with regex only?

Comment: @annahri yeah, it could, e.g. `sed -z 's/([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n/\1/'` but it's unlikely to be the best solution and that's specific to GNU sed.